# Count non-blank lines of text file in CMD/Windows

Tags: batch-file, cmd

In CMD/Batch/Windows, how do I count the number of non-blank lines of text file?

Comment: `for /F %%a in (theFile.txt) do set /A lines+=1`

Answer (score 4):

```dos
findstr "." test.txt | find /c /v ""
```

`findstr` will use the regular expression `.` (match at least a single character) against the lines in the input file and will pipe the matching lines to `find` to count the output lines.

Answer (score 2):

Just loop on findstr result, searching for at least one character (regex=.) in lines and counting.
Empty lines won't be matched.

```
@echo off

set counter=0
for /F %%a in ('findstr /R . test.txt') do (set /A counter=%counter%+1)

echo %counter%
```

if you consider that lines containing only spaces are blank, filter out lines containing only spaces too replace `.` by `/C:"[^ ]"`

```
findstr /R /C:"[^ ]" test.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply iterate through the text file content (`file.txt` in the example) using a `for /F` loop since it skips empty lines and use a counter variable:

```
set /A "COUNT=0"
for /F useback^ delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("file.txt") do set /A "COUNT+=1"
echo %COUNT%
```

The odd unquoted option string syntax `useback^ delims^=^ eol^=` is used in order to set both `eol` and `delims` to be empty (note that `eol` defaults to `;`). In case you consider lines containing only blanks (spaces, tabs) as empty, simply remove the option `delims^=^`.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
:====
set "file=c:\file.txt"
:=====
set count=1
for /f "usebackq" %a in ("%file%") do set /a count=count+1
echo %count%
```

though this will lines that contains  `;`,`=`,`,`,`<tab>`,`<space>`,`<new line>` symbols (not only spaces and tabs and new lines)